# Scaling image from php with external tool

Tags: php, image-processing, exec

In a php project I have the problem, that my provider doesn't allow me to set the memory-limit of my script higher. Therefore my script breaks if a user uploads a huge image file and I try to scale it down to safe it on the server.

My idea was to run an `exec()` command to use an external tool but did not find any examples. Is it possible to do so? Or should I try to scale the image down before upload, using javascript?

Or is there an other way to handle, I haven't even thought about..?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If your server provider is not allowing you to change `ini` directives then he isn't going to allow you to do an `exec()` IMO

Comment: Try asking your provider if they have any image resizing utilities available. You should also check if they allow exec() commands.

Comment: Thx, but the provider isn't that forthcoming. I will try to check it but I guess Robert might be right... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a client-side uploader with resizing/scaling capabilities. This will make sure that big images are scaled down *before* reaching your server. [JumpLoader](http://jumploader.com/) is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a

```
exec("convert source_image.jpg -resize 64x64 target_image.jpg")
```

to see whether ImageMagick is available.